# unable to extract text from tif image using pytesseract in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I am unable to extract text from .tif image file using pytesseract & PIL in Python.
It works well for .png, .jpg image file, it only gives error in .tif image file.
I am using Python 3.7.1 version

It gives below error while running Python code for .tif image file. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
Fax3SetupState: Bits/sample must be 1 for Group 3/4 encoding/decoding.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/u88ltuc/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Image Processing/Prog1.py", line 13, in <module>
    image_to_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
  File "C:\Users\u88ltuc\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 347, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Users\u88ltuc\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 346, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\u88ltuc\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 246, in run_and_get_output
    with save(image) as (temp_name, input_filename):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\u88ltuc\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 171, in save
    image.save(input_file_name, format=extension, **image.info)
  File "C:\Users\u88ltuc\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2102, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\u88ltuc\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1626, in _save
    raise OSError("encoder error %d when writing image file" % s)
OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file
```

Below is the Python code for it.

```
#Import modules
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

# Include tesseract executable in your path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Create an image object of PIL library
image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\u88ltuc\Desktop\12110845-e001.tif')

# pass image into pytesseract module
image_to_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')

# Print the text
print(image_to_text)
```

Below is the tif image and its link:

[image]

https://ecat.aptiv.com/docs/default-source/ecatalog-documents/12110845-e001-tif.tif?sfvrsn=3ee3b8a1_0

Comment: I am not sure is this same https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/127

Comment: hello abhik i checked the git link you provided, but i didn't understand their solution and i think this is not the same.

Comment: So why don't you change your picture's extension?Just use ``PIL`` module can do this easily.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, can you please help me in extracting text from image using just PIL module, i am not getting how I can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,you should change your image extension.
This maybe can sovle your problem:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import pytesseract

img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\u88ltuc\Desktop\12110845-e001.tif")
TempIO = BytesIO()
img.save(TempIO,format="JPEG")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(TempIO.getvalue()))

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

Or if you don't mind your desktop have two same picture,you don't need to `import BytesIO`,and here it is:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\u88ltuc\Desktop\12110845-e001.tif")
img.save(r"C:\Users\u88ltuc\Desktop\12110845-e001.jpg")
img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\u88ltuc\Desktop\12110845-e001.jpg")

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

Comment: thank you so much jizhihaoSAMA, your code is working amazing, i was searching solution for this from last 3 months.